# ocamlyacc parse error: what token?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I'm using ocamlyacc and ocamllex.  I have an error production in my grammar that signals a custom exception.  So far, I can get it to report the error position:

```
| error { raise (Parse_failure (string_of_position (symbol_start_pos ()))) }
```

But, I also want to know which token was read.  There must be a way---anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tokens are generated by lexer, hence you can use the current lexer token when error occurs :

```
  let parse_buf_exn lexbuf =
    try
      T.input T.rule lexbuf
    with exn ->
      begin
        let curr = lexbuf.Lexing.lex_curr_p in
        let line = curr.Lexing.pos_lnum in
        let cnum = curr.Lexing.pos_cnum - curr.Lexing.pos_bol in
        let tok = Lexing.lexeme lexbuf in
        let tail = Sql_lexer.ruleTail "" lexbuf in
        raise (Error (exn,(line,cnum,tok,tail)))
      end
```

`Lexing.lexeme lexbuf` is what you need. Other parts are not necessary but useful.
`ruleTail` will concat all remaining tokens into string for the user to easily locate error position. `lexbuf.Lexing.lex_curr_p` should be updated in the lexer to contain correct positions. ([source](http://repo.or.cz/w/sqlgg.git/blob/bd5f2a8553283519055cb3ba290fcd713e216079:/src/parser_utils.ml))

Comment: Great answer. I have one question, though: why do we have to use `lexbuf.Lexing.lex_curr_p` instead of `lexbuf.lex_curr_p`?

Comment: Because `lex_curr_p` belongs to `Lexing` module. Either open it or wait until OCaml gets wiser and understands unqualified record field references.

Comment: Where do you find Sql_lexer. and Error ?

Comment: Could someone pleae state explicitly where this function should be pasted ?

Answer (score 22):

The best way to debug your `ocamlyacc` parser is to set the `OCAMLRUNPARAM` param to include the character `p` - this will make the parser print all the states that it goes through, and each shift / reduce it performs.

If you are using bash, you can do this with the following command:

```
$ export OCAMLRUNPARAM='p'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that, similar to yacc, the tokens are stored in variables corresponding to the symbols in your grammar rule.  Here since there is one symbol (error), you may be able to simply output $1 using `printf`, etc.

Edit: responding to comment.

Why do you use an error terminal?  I'm reading an ocamlyacc tutorial that says a special error-handling routine is called when a parse error happens.  Like so:

> 3.1.5. The Error Reporting Routine
>
> When ther parser function detects a
>   syntax error, it calls a function
>   named `parse_error` with the string
>   "syntax error" as argument. The
>   default `parse_error` function does
>   nothing and returns, thus initiating
>   error recovery (see Error Recovery).
>   The user can define a customized
>   parse_error function in the header
>   section of the grammar file such as:

```
let parse_error s = (* Called by the parser function on error *)
  print_endline s;
  flush stdout
```

Well, looks like you only get "syntax error" with that function though.  Stay tuned for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work:

File "parser.mly", line 372: $1 refers to terminal `error', which has no argument

Comment: Can you show me the code for the entire function?  I may be able to offer more insight then.