# How to create a program combining both Parser and Lexer

Tags: ocaml, yacc, lex, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I want to build a compiler using Ocamllex/Ocamlyacc and I want to create a main program to combine both of my OcamlParser and OcamlLexer. The thing is that I know how to do it using an input in the command line like the following code:

```
let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    while true do
      let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
      print_int result; print_newline(); flush stdout
    done
  with Lexer.Eof ->
    exit 0
```

But how can I do if I want to use a file as an input; I tried something like this:

```
let file ="add.txt"
    let _ =
     let ic = open_in file in 
      try
        let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel file in
        while true do
          let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
          print_int result; print_newline(); flush stdout
        done
      with Lexer.Eof ->
        exit 0
```

But it's not really working.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific error description than "it's not really working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me. In your version, you have some syntax errors.

```
let _ =
      let file ="add.txt" in
      let i = open_in file in 
      try
        let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel i in
        while true do
          let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
          print_int result; print_newline(); flush stdout
        done
      with Lexer.Eof ->
        exit 0
```

Putting `1+2` in "add.txt" gives me `3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. Actually i'm trying to build a compiler so i can say if an input is matching a grammar or not... Do you know if it's possible to know where the syntax error is   ?

Comment: When you say the syntax error, it's about the input that you give ?

Comment: Watch the following answer, it's exactly what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046392/verbose-error-with-ocamlyacc